# Is it risky to ask for a nonexistent javascript argument?

Tags: javascript

If I have a function

```
foo()
```

that I call with no arguments most of the time, but one argument in special cases, is

```
var arg1 = arguments[0];
if (arg1) {
     <special case code>
}
```

inside the function a completely safe thing to do?

Comment: This is valid code and should not cause any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. A reasonable alternative is to name the argument, and not use the `arguments` object:

```
function foo(specialArg)
{
    if (specialArg)
    {
        // special case code
    }
}
```

Note that `if(bar)` tests the *truthiness* of `bar`. If you call `foo` with any falsy value, such as`foo(0)`, `foo(false)`, `foo(null)`, etc., the special case code will not execute in the above function (or your original function, for that matter). You can change the test to

```
if (typeof specialArg !=== 'undefined')
{
    // ...
}
```

to make sure that the special case code is executed when the argument is supplied but falsy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe. *Unless* you pass in `false`, `""`, `0`, `null` or `undefined` as an argument. It's better to check againts the value of `undefined`. (If you pass in `undefined` then tough! that's not a valid argument).

There are 3 popular checks

- `foo === undefined` **:** Standard check *but* someone (evil) might do `window.undefined = true`
- `typeof foo !== "undefined"` **:**  Checks for type and is safe.
- `foo === void 0` **:** `void 0` returns the real `undefined`

But this is prefered

```
function myFunction(foo) {
  if (foo !== undefined) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not a good way to check whether or not foo is undefined (depending on your scope).  Someone could have set undefined to something else (since undefined can be set just like any other variable - a Javascript flaw).  See this for proof: http://jsfiddle.net/xonev/v4AQH/.  The preferred method is `typeof foo !== "undefined"`. -1

Comment: @StevenOxley I mentioned there were 3 ways to handle this. I mentioned that `foo === undefined` has a weakness. I will counter argue that if I find any developer who purposely sets `undefined` to some other value deserves a slap on the wrists and that doing so is a _BUG_ that gets fixed. The preferred method is `foo !== void 0` because it's terse. Do you want to also shielding againts `undefined` being reassigned is just as pedantic as shielding against `Object.prototype = null`!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function foo(arg1){

 if (arg1){
   // Special case
 }
 else{
  // No argument

 }
 // Rest of function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you document the behaviour sufficiently I don't see anything wrong with it.

However you'd be better off checking the argument length, as opposed to how you're doing it now. Say for example you called:

```
myFunction(0);
```

It will never process the argument.

If it's a single optional argument you may be better off having it as a named argument in the function and checking if a defined value was passed in, depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The basic fact you are interested in is "was foo called with 0 or 1 argument(s)?". So I would test `arguments.length` to avoid future problems with a special argument that evaluates to false.